# do not get access to cookie

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, setcookie

I have two domains. [www.one.de and www.two.de]
on www.one.de I have a script witch makes a ajaxcall to www.two.de/collect.php

First I call on www.two.de this php-script to set a cookie:

```
$domain =".two.de";
$cookie_name = "itsmejoe";
$timestamp = time();   
$CookieSet = setcookie($cookie_name, $timestamp, time()+60*60*24*365, '/', $domain, 0);
```

in my www.one.de/collect.php-file is the following code:

```
if( isset( $_COOKIE["itsmejoe"]) ){  ...
```

My problem is that if i call collect.php (ajaxcall from www.one.de to www.two.de/collect.php) the cookie is not there.
What can I do to get access to the seted cookie?

Comment: You can only access a cookie from the same domain where it is set.

Comment: thx Andrius: For me it is set on two.de and the access is via two.de/collect. Both have the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can't be set in a different domain from another domain **directly** (security risk).

Comment: the thing here is, that the cookie is set in the same domain like the script is running